# "Attempt to reserve non-constant quantity in BSS space" error with an EQU from a different file

Tags: assembly, nasm, extern

This is going to be very specific, but I am curious.
I have an A.asm file and a B.asm file.

In A.asm there is:

```
global nodeNum

section .data
; reading consts
cmdNum          equ 9
cmdSize         equ 5
; tree consts
nodeNum         equ 8
```

Now, in B.asm:

```
extern nodeNum

section .bss
t1          resb 1
t2          resb 5*nodeNum
treevptr    resd 1
```

Assembling this gives "Attempt to reserve non-constant quantity in BSS space" error.

My questions are:

1. Why? Pseudo-command `equ` associates a constant number with a label, so why exactly this error?
2. In case of the following BSS section of B.asm

```
t1          resb 1
t2          resb (1*nodeNum + 1*nodeNum)
treevptr    resd 1
```

it assembles without errors, but `nodeNum` is 0, so `t1+1` becomes the same as `treevptr`.
How come it assembles here and not in the former case?

Comment: The symbol "address" (actually just a value in this case) `nodeNum` is only a link-time constant, not assemble-time.  But NASM needs an assemble-time constant for that, since the layout needs to be fixed for stuff generated from one `.asm` file.  You should `%include` your `equ` definitions instead of trying to use the linker.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol "address" (actually just a value in this case) `nodeNum` is only a link-time constant, not assemble-time. But NASM needs an assemble-time constant for that, since the layout needs to be fixed<sup>1</sup> for stuff generated from one `.asm` file.

**You should `%include` your `equ` definitions instead of trying to use the linker.**  (Perhaps move constants to a separate `.inc` or `.mac` that only has `equ`, `%define`, and/or macro stuff so you can include it in multiple other files.)

That will also let NASM optimize stuff like `add ecx, nodeNum` into a 3-byte `add r/m32, imm8` instead of a 6-byte `add r/m32, imm32`: when it can't see the actual numeric value of the constant, it leaves the maximum space for the linker to fill it in.  Because a small number can go in many bits, but a big number can't go in too few bits.  (Also, `extern` symbols normally *are* actual addresses that are 32 or 64-bit values.)

---

Footnote 1: There probably isn't a relocation type that would allow the linker to expand a variable amount of zeros. And if there is for ELF `.o` files, NASM doesn't support it.  If two symbols are defined in the same `.asm` (e.g. on either side of what you're trying to do), NASM treats the distance between them as an assemble-time constant, e.g. for stuff like `mov eax, foo - bar` to fill in a numeric value as assemble time, or the well known `times 510-($-$$) db 0` which needs to know how many bytes have been emitted into the current section so it can pad to reach 510 bytes.

Comment: NASM include files are usually named `.inc` or `.mac`

Comment: @ecm: Oh right, thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.
I used the the preprocessor with a `%define` directive as:

```
%define BUFFLEN1  500

...

section .bss

my_buffer:  resb BUFFLEN1
```

Comment: `equ` would work fine as long as it's in the same asm source file.